# Taking the area under a square pulse

Tags: python

Hey Stack Overflow community,

I've been given a series of datasets that resembles a square pulse, and ideally looks like the following:
[image]

This particular plot is composed of many sets of data.

I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve just the area under the square pulse with the assumption that "spikes" may appear before or on the actual pulse itself.

The method I've tried is to cut everything before and after the pulse, and look for spikes that may occur on the actual pulse by looking at how much each value deviates from the mode peak found. However, this seems less than adequate as my implementation requires going through each point multiple times generating quite a large time complexity, and the file sizes are pretty huge.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Once you've "cut everything before and after the pulse", can't you find the mean height of the datapoints within the pulse (one traversal) and then find the area by multiplying that mean height by the width of the pulse (which you would already have, as you cut out everything but the pulse)?

Comment: @thisisbenmanley - yeah that's what I'm doing right now, but the method I use to cut those endpoints leaves a lot to be desired. Essentially, I'm looping through the entire dataset once to calculate the mode peak, a second time to delete everything below that peak, and then continuing with the rest of my calculations. Problem is this doesn't take care of early peaks, the endpoints may or may not be a long distance from the next point, and this is adds quite a bit of time complexity.

Comment: I'm thinking making a fit for the points would be more efficient, however I wanted to see if anyone with more experience dealing with signals could offer a better solution.